# Move text files in a folder c#

Tags: c#

I have a folder that contains multiple text files and I would like to read them to get the contents of some lines and then move that file to a "backup" folder.

The path of my "backup" folder is :

> \SRVWEB001\spool_interface\PVCHARGE\Backup\

The path that contains my text files :

> \SRVWEB001\spool_interface\PVCHARGE\UTS600\

I managed to read the lines of a file and store them in a List but when I want to copy my text files in the "backup" folder I can not copy them because I have this error : "Unable to create an existing file." (System.IO.IO Exception) except that my file does not yet exist in the folder ..

This is my code :

```
        [WebMethod]
    public string enTete()
    {
        // Stocke une à une les lignes du fichier
        List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
        // Stocke l'en-tête
        List<string> enTete = new List<string>();

        // Chemin du dossier contenant les fichiers 
        string dirPath = @"\\SRVWEB001\spool_interface\PVCHARGE\UTS600\";
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

        // Si il existe des fichiers txt dans le dossier
        if (Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.txt").Length != 0)
        {
            // Pour chaque fichier 
            foreach (var fichier in d.GetFiles("*.txt"))
            {
                // Lis le fichier 
                using (FileStream fs = fichier.OpenRead())
                {
                    byte[] b = new byte[fs.Length];
                    int counter = 0;
                    string line;
                    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));

                    // Récupération de chaque ligne dans la List<string> allLines
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        allLines.Add(line);
                        counter++;
                    }

                    // Fermeture du fichier
                    file.Close();

                    // Dossier "Backup"
                    string backupPath = @"\\SRVWEB001\spool_interface\PVCHARGE\Backup\";
                    DirectoryInfo d2 = new DirectoryInfo(backupPath);

                    // Fichier à déplacer
                    string filePath = dirPath + fichier.ToString();

                    if (Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                    {
                        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath);

                        foreach (string s in files)
                        {
                            // Déplace le fichier dans le dossier "Backup"
                            File.Move(s, backupPath);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
                    }

                    // Récupération des colonnes de l'en-tête dans un tableau (correspond à la ligne 105)
                    char[] separator = new char[] { '\t' };
                    string[] colonnes = allLines[105].Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    // Affichage des colonnes
                    return colonnes[0]+" "+colonnes[1]+" "+colonnes[2]+" "+colonnes[3]+" "+colonnes[4]+" "+colonnes[5]+" "+colonnes[6] + " " +colonnes[7] + " " +colonnes[8] + " " +colonnes[9]+" "+ colonnes[10] + " " + colonnes[11] + " " + colonnes[12] + " " + colonnes[13] + " " + colonnes[14];
                }
            }

            return "Succès";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Pas de fichier texte";
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a filename to File.Move - not a directoy name. Instead of:

```
File.Move(s, backupPath);
```

try

```
File.Move(s, Path.Combine(backupPath, Path.GetFilename(s)));
```

Comment: Is it possible to read multiple text files and move them one by one in my folder ? Because my code works for a single file but not for all the files in my folder, I do not understand why

Comment: It should work, but you could easily run inte trouble with open files. I recommend that you do NOT work with .StreamReader and/or .OpenRead, unless you have really big files. Try File.ReadAllLines/File.WriteAllLines etc so you don't have to remember close the files properly.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of File.Move needs to be the path & filename that you want to move the file to. The reason you are getting the exception is that without including the filename you are trying to move the file & create it with the same name as your backup folder.